# Can we use keyword arguments and curry until all arguments are received?

Tags: python, functional-programming, currying, partials

Can we use keyword arguments and *curry* a function until all arguments are received in any order?

For example I have this code:

```
def create_folder_transformer(folder):
    return lambda predicate: lambda file_transformer: map(file_transformer,
        filter(predicate,
            os.listdir(folder)))
```

I can create a `folder_transformer` with a specific folder and then mention the`predicate etc. But it has a specific order. However, I don't think it need to be tied to that order.

I would like to achieve something like this instead:

1. If I pass `predicate`, I get a partial function that takes `folder`
   and `file_transformer` as arguments. Now if I supply `folder`, I get a partial function that takes `file_transformer`.
2. If I pass `file_transformer`, I get a partial function that takes `predicate` and `folder` as arguments. Now if I supply `predicate`, I get a partial function that takes `folder`.

In short, is there an inbuilt partial creator that *recursively* keeps on generating partial functions until all inputs are obtained; if inputs are satisfied just execute the code. I believe it is called *currying* in Haskell and it is how functions perform by default.

Use cases where I think it might help:

1. When I am transforming a specific `folder` with `n` operations,
   creating a partial with `folder` will be better.
2. When I am having a specific predicate like - filter out `mp4` files across many folders - a partial with a `predicate` like `string.endswith(".mp4")` will be better.

---

I read the partial [docs](http://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial) but these partials don't return partials if I haven't filled in some args. But since I have declared it as `None`, I can't expect it either. Ideally, I would like my **function** itself to behave like that without even worrying about using an additional function like partial i.e it should be baked into my function.

```
def folder_transformer(folder=None, predicate=None, transformer=None):
    return map(transformer, filter(predicate, os.listdir(folder)))

file_transformer = partial(folder_transformer, predicate=os.path.isfile)

# This gives me a "map" object, but I want another partial takes "transformer".
current_transformer = file_transformer(folder=folder)
# This works, but my question is can I make my function do this automatically. 
current_transformer = partial(file_transformer,folder=folder)
```

Comment: Any good reason you are reinventing the wheel and not using `functools.partial`?

Comment: @DeepSpace, Can I use keyword arguments like the way I described above?

Comment: Yes, please read the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came with a small script for my **personal** use.

PS: If anyone knows a library that can do something similar, please let me know.

```
import inspect

def curry(function):
    original_func = function
    original_args = inspect.signature(function).parameters

    def wrapper(**kwargs):
        call = True
        current_args = {}
        for each in original_args:
            if kwargs.get(each):
                current_args[each] = kwargs.get(each)
            else:
                call = False
        if call:
            original_func(**current_args)
        else:
            def partial(**nargs):
                current_args.update(nargs)
                return wrapper(**current_args)
            return partial

    return wrapper

@curry
def foo(a=None, b=None, c=None):
    print(a, b, c)

# first partial
bar_with_a = bar(a=1)
# next partial
bar_with_a_and_b = bar_with_a(b=1)
# next partial
bar_with_a_and_b = bar_with_a_and_b(b=2)
# next partial
bar_with_a_and_b = bar_with_a_and_b(a=2)
# call
bar_with_a_and_b(c=2)
```